# Agreguemos etiqueta [propuesta-de-faq] para las propuestas de FAQ

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, meta, propuesta-de-faq

## En breve y directo

Agregar la etiqueta [propuesta-de-faq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/propuesta-de-faq).

## Explicación

FAQ: Acrónimo de la frase en inglés "Frequently Asked Question" que significa Preguntas Frecuentes (PP.FF.)

Estaba pensando escribir un FAQ así que fui a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) para revisar las indicaciones en la materia y di con [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) donde se indica que si el FAQ que uno quiere proponer no está en el FAQ se publique una pregunta con la etiqueta [`faq-proposed`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) ([propuesta-de-faq](/questions/tagged/propuesta-de-faq) en castellano). Me parece que para la comunidad de programadores FAQ es un término que podría entenderse al menos por cualquiera que quiera proponer una **pregunta frecuente** y por consistencia con el resto de sitios de la red podría ser "sano" usar [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) (como sinónimo de la versión en castellano [propuesta-de-faq](/questions/tagged/propuesta-de-faq)).

Curiosamente aún no hay ninguna FAQ así que esta pregunta resultó ser tanto un solicitud como una oportunidad para crear la etiqueta en cuestión.

## Referencias

[Preguntas frecuentes - Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preguntas_frecuentes)

Comment: Versión en portugués: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade . . . . PS: creo que la tag *master* tendría que ser en español: [meta-tag:propuesta-para-faq] . . . . PS2: en muchos casos, nos será más fácil seguir el ejemplo de SOpt (en cuanto a las cosas básicas, me refiero)

Comment: @brasofilo: En lo personal prefiero que el término que se refiere al concepto principal se escriba primero, por otro lado, no creo que debamos ser "más papistas que el Papa". En relación a SOpt, creo que es bueno aprender de su experiencia pero es importante distinguir cuando las decisiones son debido a restricciones técnicas y cuando se deben a preferencias de la comunidad. ¿Participas en SOpt?

Comment: Yo creo que un site *en español* tendría que tener las tags en español, y hacer sinónimas algunas traducciones donde el término también se usa en inglés. Ahora mismo, que yo sepa, no funcionan las tags acentuadas aquí en SOes. . . . . Sí, participo allí y estoy intentando tener cuidado en no usar ejemplos de SOpt como si fueran el camino que SOes tenga que seguir. Hay algunas cosas del meta-FAQ que creo que puedo adelantar aquí con lo que ya existe allí (especialmente las que fueron creadas a partir de Meta.so y Meta.se).

Comment: @brasofilo: ACK

Comment: Recupero la etiqueta [meta-tag:faq-proposed] para que al menos una pregunta la tenga y así 1: se sugiera al ir a etiquetar las preguntas y 2: no se pierda la información wiki.

Comment: Pedí a los moderadores que la renombraran a [meta-tag:propuesta-de-faq] y queda [meta-tag:faq-proposed] como sinónima. Así lo tenemos todo en castellano.

Comment: ya dejo de editar esta pregunta, creo que ya no veo nada cambiable XD Perdonad el spam

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias. Estaba a punto de sugerirte que publicaras una nueva :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Hecho. Véase [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) y [propuesta-de-faq](/questions/tagged/propuesta-de-faq), sinónimas con la versión en castellano como principal.

## Explicación

Las etiquetas en meta usan le prefijo `meta-tag` en lugar de `tag` el cual corresponde a las etiquetas del sitio principal.

Nota: Además de que "he vuelto" y espero continuar participando frecuentemente en el 2017, me he encontrado una pregunta publicada por alguien más usando la etiqueta.

## Referencias

- https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags
- [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-que-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%C3%B3n-para-comentar-que-alternativa-tengo)