# ¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?

Tags: soporte, faq, usuarios-nuevos, reputación, privilegios

> Esta publicación es traducción del original en inglés [Why
>   do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Los usuarios con menos de 50 puntos de reputación no pueden escribir comentarios en preguntas ni en respuestas que no hayan publicado ellos mismos.

- ¿Por qué?
- ¿Qué debo hacer entonces?
- No puedo escribir una buena respuesta sin más información.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Si tu formulas una pregunta siendo un usuario de menos de 50 pts de reputación puedes comentar en cualquier respuesta que se haya publicado en la pregunta formulada, de ahí en fuera se aplica el limite

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## ¿Por qué existe este límite?

Sabemos que los nuevos usuarios podrían aportar comentarios valiosos y que podríamos perdernos algunas de esas contribuciones por requerir 50 puntos de reputación para habilitar esta función.

Sin embargo, la historia y la experiencia nos ha mostrado que las desventajas de permitir a todos comentar libremente son mayores que los pocos buenos comentarios que se pierden:

- Hay serios problemas de spam. Los filtros automatizados no pueden atrapar todo.
- Entre comentarios reales, también encontraríamos cosas como "Tengo el mismo problema" o "Estoy de acuerdo". Esos comentarios no agregan ningún valor y deben ser eliminados de forma manual.
- Los comentarios son muy dolorosos de moderar. Los sitios de Stack Exchange son moderados por los miembros de la comunidad (votos, banderas, colas de revisión) que funcionan muy bien para preguntas y respuestas, pero no para los comentarios. Los comentarios no pueden votarse en contra, ni cerrarse, ni siquiera la búsqueda del sitio los tiene en cuenta (ni queremos agregar estas funciones).
- Los comentarios son ciudadanos de segunda clase en la red de Stack Exchange, no fueron diseñados para almacenar información permanente. Podrían ser eliminados en cualquier momento. Por lo general, **la información verdaderamente importante debería incorporarse a la pregunta o respuesta.**

Generando buenas respuestas obtendrás los 50 puntos de reputación rápidamente. Además, aún puedes sugerir ediciones que mejoren una pregunta o respuesta y cada vez que lo hagas obtendrás 2 puntos de reputación.

## Pero quiero contribuir ahora, ¿Qué debo hacer entonces?

## ¿Puedo comentar en una respuesta?

#### - No.

Preguntar y responder, las funciones principales del sitio están disponibles para todos los usuarios sin importar su reputación.

Cuidado, esto no significa que hay que usar las respuestas para hacer comentarios. Están sujetos a ser eliminados e implica más trabajo manual.

Para pedir aclaraciones, o comentar sobre una respuesta **debes esperar hasta que tengas el privilegio de comentar.**

## Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo escribir una buena respuesta?

- Si estás seguro que puedes proveer una respuesta real, te animamos a seguir adelante, pero asegúrate que sea una respuesta válida y completa a la pregunta.
- Si encuentras un error en una respuesta existente, menciónalo en tu respuesta, pero asegúrate de incluir una solución alternativa que se sostenga por sí misma. No copies y pegues el comentario original dentro del cuadro "respuesta".

## Pero, ¿Cómo puedo escribir una buena respuesta sin más información?

Las respuestas no tienen que ser exhaustivas o infalibles, deben intentar responder a la pregunta. Es perfectamente válido responder diciendo: "No estoy seguro de qué causa el problema, pero si tal cosa es X, lo puedes resolver haciendo Y. Si eso no ayuda, intenta Z y hazme saber qué resultado obtienes". Además, si luego se publica más información en la pregunta, puedes editar tu respuesta para que sea más precisa. Éste es un buen hábito, incluso para aquellos que pueden comentar.

Y Bienvenido a la comunidad, ¡buena suerte!

> Esta respuesta es traducción del original en inglés [Why
> do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/268782)